# Errors while implementing mask rcnn (OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t)

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, mask, faster-rcnn

I'm trying to implementing Mask R-CNN for my project. I've been trying to detect motorbike from the images. I've annotated images using supervise.ly https://supervise.ly . after various changes in the code an error 
  File "skimage/draw/_draw.pyx", line 217, in skimage.draw._draw._polygon 
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t

is shown

The annotations is as follows:

```
  {"description": "", "tags": [], "size": {"height": 720, "width": 1280}, "objects": [{"description": "", "bitmap": null, "tags": [], "classTitle": "bike", "points": {"exterior": [[854, 431], [868, 426], [888, 428], [891, 421], [885, 412], [888, 399], [896, 396], [901, 395], [906, 387], [913, 377], [919, 373], [925, 370], [936, 367], [954, 365], [966, 362], [975, 359], [982, 352], [980, 342], [984, 328], [991, 320], [996, 317], [1002, 316], [1009, 318], [1014, 327], [1016, 337], [1016, 343], [1021, 352], [1028, 358], [1033, 364], [1037, 374], [1037, 379], [1035, 396], [1039, 401], [1051, 402], [1061, 408], [1066, 422], [1069, 429], [1071, 449], [1071, 455], [1071, 465], [1069, 471], [1058, 471], [1054, 479], [1046, 485], [1036, 491], [1024, 494], [1010, 495], [998, 490], [993, 482], [980, 482], [974, 482], [968, 482], [959, 483], [943, 486], [936, 483], [933, 474], [931, 469], [919, 465], [905, 473], [893, 481], [884, 484], [876, 485], [871, 486], [859, 486], [850, 486], [844, 484], [839, 481], [833, 465], [837, 454], [844, 444], [849, 438]], "interior": []}}]}
```

I'm stuck on these images. either I've to start over and manually annotated many images. or I can use supervisely, which is very helpful in annotations. I'm guessing the main culprit is the dataset class.

```
############################################################
#  Dataset
############################################################

       def sort_filenames(alist):
           import re
           def atoi(text):
               return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
           def natural_keys(text):
               return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]
           #alist=["something1","something12","something17","something2","something25","so       mething29"]
           alist.sort(key=natural_keys)
           #print(alist)
       class bikeDataset(utils.Dataset):



    def load_bike(self, dataset_dir, subset,start_size,end_size):
        """Load a subset of the bike dataset.
        dataset_dir: Root directory of the dataset.
        subset: Subset to load: train or val
        """
        # Add classes. We have only one class to add.
        self.add_class("bike", 1, "bike")

        # Train or validation dataset?
        assert subset in ["train", "val"]
        dataset_dir = os.path.join("/home/hunain/Mask_RCNN/samples/bike/dataset", subset)


        # Load annotations
        # VGG Image Annotator (up to version 1.6) saves each image in the form:
        # { 'filename': '28503151_5b5b7ec140_b.jpg',
        #   'regions': {
        #       '0': {
        #           'region_attributes': {},
        #           'shape_attributes': {
        #               'all_points_x': [...],
        #               'all_points_y': [...],
        #               'name': 'polygon'}},
        #       ... more regions ...
        #   },
        #   'size': 100202
        # }
        # We mostly care about the x and y coordinates of each region
        # Note: In VIA 2.0, regions was changed from a dict to a list.
        #annotations = json.load(open(os.path.join(dataset_dir, "via_region_data.json")))
        print(dataset_dir+'..........................................................................')
        filenames= os.listdir(dataset_dir)


        list_file =[]
        name_count=0
        for f in filenames:
            temp1 , temp2 = (f.split('.',1))
            temp3 = temp1 + ".png"
            list_file.append(temp3)
            name_count=name_count+1
        sort_filenames(list_file)
        #print(str(name_count)+'....................................................................................')

            #comment hata kay dekh lo, naam print kardeta hai image wali file kay
        annotations=[]    
        for i in range(start_size,end_size):
            annotations.append(json.load(open(os.path.join(dataset_dir, "out"+str(i)+".png.json"))))
        #print(annotations)
        #annotations = [a for a in annotations if a['objects']]
        #print(annotations)
        count=0
        image_dir=""
        for annot in annotations:
            count=count+1
            if annot['objects']:
                for i in annot['objects']:
                    points = i['points']
                    exterior = points['exterior']
                    #print (exterior)

            # load_mask() needs the image size to convert polygons to masks.
            # Unfortunately, VIA doesn't include it in JSON, so we must read
            # the image. This is only managable since the dataset is tiny.
                    if (subset=="train"):
                        image_dir="/home/hunain/Mask_RCNN/samples/bike/dataset/images"
                    else:
                        image_dir="/home/hunain/Mask_RCNN/samples/bike/dataset/images2"
                    image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, list_file[count])
                    image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
                    height, width = image.shape[:2]
                    all_x=[]
                    all_y=[]
                    polygon=[]
                    for i in exterior:
                        all_x.append(i[0])
                        all_y.append(i[1])
                    #print(all_x)
                    #print(all_y)
                    polygon.append(all_x)
                    polygon.append(all_y)
                    #print(polygon)
                    self.add_image(
                            "bike",
                            image_id=list_file[count],  # use file name as a unique image id
                            path=image_path,
                            width=1280, height=720,
                            polygons=copy.deepcopy(polygon))
                    all_x.clear()
                    all_y.clear()
                    polygon.clear()



    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        print('We are in Load mask function.................')
        """Generate instance masks for an image.
       Returns:
        masks: A bool array of shape [height, width, instance count] with
            one mask per instance.
        class_ids: a 1D array of class IDs of the instance masks.
        """
        # If not a bike dataset image, delegate to parent class.
        image_info = self.image_info[image_id]
        #print(image_info['polygons'])
        if image_info["source"] != "bike":
            return super(self.__class__, self).load_mask(image_id)

        # Convert polygons to a bitmap mask of shape
        # [height, width, instance_count]
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        mask = np.zeros([info["height"], info["width"], len(info["polygons"])],
                        dtype=np.uint8)
        for i, p in enumerate(info["polygons"]):
            #print(p)
            # Get indexes of pixels inside the polygon and set them to 1
            rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(p[0], p[1])
            mask[rr, cc, i] = 1

        # Return mask, and array of class IDs of each instance. Since we have
        # one class ID only, we return an array of 1s
        return mask.astype(np.bool), np.ones([mask.shape[-1]], dtype=np.int32)

    def image_reference(self, image_id):
        print('We are in image_reference function..............')

        """Return the path of the image."""
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        if info["source"] == "bike":
            return info["path"]
        else:
            super(self.__class__, self).image_reference(image_id)


       def train(model):
    print('We are in train function...............')
    """Train the model."""
    # Training dataset.
    dataset_train = bikeDataset()
    dataset_train.load_bike(args.dataset, "train",1,325)
    dataset_train.prepare()
    # needs a revision. isko revise karna hai file_numers ko.

    # Validation dataset
    dataset_val = bikeDataset()
    dataset_val.load_bike(args.dataset, "val",326,400)
    dataset_val.prepare()

    # *** This training schedule is an example. Update to your needs ***
    # Since we're using a very small dataset, and starting from
    # COCO trained weights, we don't need to train too long. Also,
    # no need to train all layers, just the heads should do it.
    print("Training network heads")
    model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
                learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE,
                epochs=2,
                layers='heads')


       def color_splash(image, mask):
    print('We are in color_splash function.......................')
    """Apply color splash effect.
    image: RGB image [height, width, 3]
    mask: instance segmentation mask [height, width, instance count]

    Returns result image.
    """
    # Make a grayscale copy of the image. The grayscale copy still
    # has 3 RGB channels, though.
    gray = skimage.color.gray2rgb(skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)) * 255
    # Copy color pixels from the original color image where mask is set
    if mask.shape[-1] > 0:
        # We're treating all instances as one, so collapse the mask into one layer
        mask = (np.sum(mask, -1, keepdims=True) >= 1)
        splash = np.where(mask, image, gray).astype(np.uint8)
    else:
        splash = gray.astype(np.uint8)
    return splash


       def detect_and_color_splash(model, image_path=None, video_path=None):
    print('We are in detect_and_color_splash function................')
    assert image_path or video_path

    # Image or video?
    if image_path:
        # Run model detection and generate the color splash effect
        print("Running on {}".format(args.image))
        # Read image
        image = skimage.io.imread(args.image)
        # Detect objects
        r = model.detect([image], verbose=1)[0]
        # Color splash
        splash = color_splash(image, r['masks'])
        # Save output
        file_name = "splash_{:%Y%m%dT%H%M%S}.png".format(datetime.datetime.now())
        skimage.io.imsave(file_name, splash)
    elif video_path:
        import cv2
        # Video capture
        vcapture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        width = int(vcapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        height = int(vcapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        fps = vcapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

        # Define codec and create video writer
        file_name = "splash_{:%Y%m%dT%H%M%S}.avi".format(datetime.datetime.now())
        vwriter = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name,
                                  cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),
                                  fps, (width, height))

        count = 0
        success = True
        while success:
            print("frame: ", count)
            # Read next image
            success, image = vcapture.read()
            if success:
                # OpenCV returns images as BGR, convert to RGB
                image = image[..., ::-1]
                # Detect objects
                r = model.detect([image], verbose=0)[0]
                # Color splash
                splash = color_splash(image, r['masks'])
                # RGB -> BGR to save image to video
                splash = splash[..., ::-1]
                # Add image to video writer
                vwriter.write(splash)
                count += 1
        vwriter.release()
    print("Saved to ", file_name)
```

I expect the model to acquire images and start training these images. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the line of the code which is throwing the error?

Comment: rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(np.array(p[0]), np.array(p[1]))

Comment: The error you showed is only for one image, or does it happen for every image you labeled? Did you try doing smaller "test" annotations, I mean polygons with less edges?

Comment: I managed the annotations in another way, I created the mask images using the https://github.com/mcordts/cityscapesScripts, and modified that part of the code to accept images instead of polygons, but I find your approach better

Comment: Also did you check all the polygons edges are int smaller than 65536? Perhaps there is a format problem with the file and it reads the numbers wrong

Comment: The error, I'm facing is for every image. I really don't want to annotate all other images manually. I'm trying to utilize the annotations generated by supervise.ly. I've seen your link. But my approach generates mask from polygons in annotations. Thank you reading my problem.